# Why the "var" keyword can't be used with the comma operator?

Tags: javascript

The following spinet is valid JS:

```
var foo;
if (foo = true, foo) {
}
```

But this one isn't:

```
if ((var foo = true), foo) {
}
```

Why?

Comment: `var` isn't valid there - it's part of the syntax of javascript

Comment: Because the `if` condition needs to be an expression, not a statement. There’s no way to put a `var` declaration into expression context.

Comment: Nothing really to do with ES6. It's just plain old normal JS.

Comment: Surrounding anything in Javascript with parentheses tells the JS Engine that the contained statements should be evaluated as an expression.  Variable declarations are not valid in an expression

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because

```
foo = true
```

is an [AssignmentExpression](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#prod-AssignmentExpression), which is an [Expression](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#prod-Expression), so you can wrap it inside a [ParenthesizedExpression](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#prod-ParenthesizedExpression):

> ```
> ParenthesizedExpression[Yield]:
>     (Expression[In, ?Yield])
> ```

But

```
var foo = true
```

is a [VariableStatement](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#prod-VariableStatement), which is a [Statement](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#prod-Statement), not an Expression.